# Why is my full stack triggered experience in Sitecore Personalize failing with the error NO DECISION?

Tags: personalization, sitecore-personalize, decisioning

When I have created a Full Stack Triggered Experience in Sitecore Personalise that is using a Decision Model. The Full Stack Triggered Experience is failing when it is triggered with the error NO DECISION in the execution report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a triggered full stack experience/experiment is using a decision model, the decision model **must return an offer**. If an offer is not returned from the decision model connected to your the full stack triggered experience will fail with the error NO_DECISION.

To avoid the NO_DECISION error, return any offer from your decision model. This can be a dummy offer that is not used in your full stack triggered experience.

This is not the case for Full Stack Interactive experiences/experiments or Web experiences/experiments. For Full Stack Interactive or Web experiences a decision model can be used that is not returning an offer.